# SPNEGO and Delegation in Java

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, kerberos, delegation, spnego

I use SPNEGO to authenticate my webapp. I would like to use ticket delegation to authenticate to LDAP on server side. But there is no ticket cache on server side since login (kinit) is done on client side. How can I do sso please?

```
CLIENT --(spnego)---> SERVER ----(?delegation?)---> LDAP
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's maintaining its own ticket cache. I have exaclty that setup up an running. What did you implement so far?

Comment: Michael-O, can you tell me please how you retrieve, on the server side, the delegated TGT obtained with SPNEGO on the client side? Thank you

Comment: Assuming that you have sucessfully established the `GSSContext` you can check with [`getDelegState()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/ietf/jgss/GSSContext.html#getCredDelegState()) if the initiator (client) has cred delegation turned on. If `true` is returned, retrieve it the `GSSCredential` with [`getDelegCred()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/ietf/jgss/GSSContext.html#getDelegCred()) and save this some where. But remember that this credential expires after a certain period.